# Am I just misusing objects in this random lotto generator code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've gotten a Random Lotto Generator script to work in JavaScript in one game. Now, I'm trying to get it to function for multiple Lotto games and figured Objects were the best way to adjust to the different formats of each game to account for different number pools, different selected numbers, 'bonus balls', duplicate numbers, etc.

```
const game = [{name: "Lotto Texas", balls: 6, numbers: 54, start: 1, duplicates: false, bonusBall: false, results: []},
{name: "Pick 3", balls: 3, numbers: 10, start: 0, duplicates: true, bonusBall: false, results: []},
{name: "Powerball", balls: 5, numbers: 69, start: 1, duplicates: false, bonusBall: true, bonusNumbers: 26, results: [], bonus: []}];

game.forEach (lottoResults()); // gets results

function lottoResults(){
    this.results.length = this.balls; //Here is where the error occurs. This is supposed to assign the balls property to the results array's length value.
 
    if (!this.duplicates){ //checks if duplicates allowed
        this.results.forEach(duplicateCheck());
    }
    else{
       this.results.forEach(lottoBall())
    }
    
    if(this.bonusBall){
        this.bonus.push(lottoBall(this.bonusNumbers, this.start)); //assigns a number to bonus ball
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set a blank array initialized in each object, with the amount with the 'balls' property (referring to lotto balls) setting how big the array is dependent on the game. However, anytime I try to set that up, I keep getting an Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function. I've tried setting the object property value to a primitive variable, establishing the array length within the initialized object variables, but still get the same error in some form. Am I just misusing the object and should be calling the values differently?

Answer (score 2):

You are *invoking* `lottoResults` here within `forEach` by placing `()` after the function name

```js
game.forEach (lottoResults());
```

Instead, you should pass the function like this

```js
game.forEach (lottoResults);
```

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

Note: Same thing applies to `duplicateCheck` and `lottoBall` passed to forEach, remove the `()`

Comment: Thanks. I corrected it, while it seemed to correct something, It still doesn't seem to like my attempt to assign this.balls to this.results.length. Saying "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'length').

Comment: I suspected that you would run into that, but I didn't know the context so I didn't add the answer for that. 

It's basically because `this` doesn't refer to your `game` object. Instead, you should modify the definition of `lottoResults` to include each `object` in the `game` array

so `function lottoResults() {` should be `function lottoResults(gameObj) {` and then replace all `this` keywords with `gameObj`

Answer (score 0):

The concept of this in JavaScript can be rather difficult to grasp. And occasionally, even experienced programmers may struggle with it.

As @Vin_it mentioned above, you're use of the this keyword is not referring to each item in the game array. If you execute the following code in your browser's console, you will notice that this is referring to the Window object. Don't worry if you don't get it straight away, but save [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and refer to it in the future when you face this issue.

```js
//This is a reference to the Window Object:

function lottoResults(){
  console.log(this)
}

lottoResults()
```

Instead of using "this", you can iterate over arrays easily using the following construction:

```js
forEach((item) => { 
  //do somthing with the item:
  duplicateCheck(item.results)
})
```

As shown above, for sake of clarity, you might move your extra forEach inside the duplicateCheck function. Just set it to receive an array as parameter and adjust your code accordingly. This way you can keep the all code involved in verifying duplicates isolated.

Also, when you specify the length of an array as you are doing in the code below, you are basically creating and empty array of a given length with undefined items. If this was undesired, check the [length property documentation in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length#create_empty_array_of_fixed_length).

```js
function lottoResults(){
    this.results.length = this.balls; //here
    //...
}
```

While this answer doesn't doesn't show exactly how to write your code, I hope it explains why you are getting "Uncaught TypeError: Undefined" when using this.
Keep up the good work.